# ReferenceError: self is not defined. How can I import third party funtion in my next app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, import, referenceerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFXhp.png)

The dynamic function only return a component.
How can I import canvasDatagrid function to my component？

I used setTimeout to import in useEffect but it didn't work.

I just wanna use canvasDatagrid in my next app.

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of a source code, but paste your source code. That will help in receiving more helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using dynamic import in parent component.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ydZL.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).